# How to validate sql table constraints when inserting from c# or vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, c#-4.0

I wonder if there are some best practice to do the data validations before we actually insert it to table?

e.g. table has a nvarchar(50) column field with required (set as not null in table). So before we insert it in table we need to provide a summary to user that all data (500-20000) records are valid and will be inserted.

As per the requirement, if one record violating the validations (Length, required, null etc.) then data cannot be inserted.

So we need to provide a summary to the user about which records failed in validations.

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do here. Maybe you create a grid with all the rows that failed and include a new column with the reason why?

Comment: I think the best practice is to do what you described.

Comment: Only you know all the validation rules, so you should check the data before inserting and provide a userfriendly error message if there is something wrong. In addition you can use check constraints for specific columns in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

If there are possibly 20k records to be inserted and only a few that fail validation, I would only show the user invalid records. Then I think it would be best to call out specifically on each record what is wrong. This could be done in a grid and highlight the cells that are invalid.